# Как передать массив байт по Json

Tags: java, postgresql, spring, jpa, nhibernate

Приветствую! Есть необходимость передать массив байтов по json. Но у меня это не получается. Проект написан на Java с использованием Spring-Hibenate-JPA.

Сущность News в которой я объявляю поле `image_url`, база Postgres, поле в базе имеет тип BYTEA.

```
@Column(name = "image_url", nullable = false, length = 10000)
private byte[] image_url;
```

Добавляю в базу массив "b":

```
String url = "http://78.24.216.172:8080/images/" + nameImage + ".jpeg";
byte[] b = url.getBytes();
```

Далее просто запрашиваю все записи, таким образом:

```
@Query("select distinct p from News p ORDER BY p.id DESC")
List<News> findNewsNew();
```

Но почему-то в image_url не массив байт а просто строка, как мне решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте про base64 и проблема отпадет.

Comment: Владимир, это понятно, но мне нужен именно массив байт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему заменой библиотеки для Json, раньше использовал Jackson, теперь перешел на Gson, и массив байтов отображается правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте преобразовать строку в байт массив.

```html
 public byte[] stringToHex(String string)
 {
  return new BigInteger(string, 16).toByteArray();
 }
```